# Uniform convergence on compact subsets does not imply convergence in measure?

Tags: real-analysis

I just finished proving that uniform convergence implies convergence in measure. Does this implication also hold for $f_{n} \to f$ uniformly on compact subsets?

Edit: I think $f_{n}(x) = x^{n}$ on $(0,1)$ might work as a counterexample. Nevermind. Perhaps $f_{n}(x) = 1 - x^{n}$ on $(0,1)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f_n=\chi_{[n,\infty)}$. Clearly $f_n\rightarrow  0$ uniformly on compact subsets, but does not converge to anything in measure.

For finite measure sets $E$ the implication is correct and should follow from a rather direct $\epsilon-\delta$ proof, choosing a compact $K\subset E$ with $\mu (E-K)$ very small.